# Calculating Sums Of Maths

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, resultant

I need to use Pythagoras’ theorem to calculate the magnitude of the resultant. I've calculated the horizontal and vertical components. I've attached the image here:

I've added up by vertical components to give me -86N and my horizontal components to give me 88767N

If I'm correct it would be $\sqrt(7.77)^2 + 865.4^2$ giving me the answer of square rooting it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't check the full calculation but the way to obtain the magnitude for the resultant for two orthogonal vectors/force $\vec A$ and $\vec B$ is correct

$$|\vec R|=\sqrt{|\vec A|^2+|\vec B|^2}$$

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Maths Youa are welcome! Bye